# Xcode 11 doesn't see Launch screen files

Tags: xcode, cordova

so I've updated to Xcode 11 and for some reason I'm not able to select any Launch screen files, App Icons are OK. 
On Xcode 10 it worked fine. In screenshot you can see that I have the files there. Do you have any suggestions on how to fix it? I'm struggling on this for a few hours now.

[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqbYZ.png)

[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpY2F.png)

Answer (score 1):

You should setup it in target build setting

Asset Catalog Launch Image Set Name with your LaunchImage name

But in 2019 WWDC show, Apple will reject app which not use launch screen with storyboard after 2020/04.

Comment: I was really unable to set it there :-). However I gave some time to storyboard and I'm all set now!